# C# HTTP Server Socket Error

Tags: c#, sockets, http, asynchronous, tcp

I have a simple application, that acts as an HTTP Server, that only accepts HTTP POST.

It has been working great the past few months, however I have noticed a specific case where an error appears in my LOG and it does not make sense to me.

Before I unnecessarily complicate it. let me show you the function where the error is happening.

```
 public async Task HandlePostRequestAsync()
    {          
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        if (HttpHeaders.ContainsKey("Content-Length"))
        {
            var contentLen = Convert.ToInt32(HttpHeaders["Content-Length"]);
            if (contentLen > MaxPostSize)
            {
                throw new Exception($"POST Content-Length({contentLen}) too big for this simple server");
            }
            byte[] buf = new byte[BufSize];
            int toRead = contentLen;
            while (toRead > 0)
            {
                int numread = await _inputStream.ReadAsync(buf, 0, Math.Min(BufSize, toRead));
                if (numread == 0)
                {
                    if (toRead == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    //NOTE: Some times getting error here, seems to keep happening after first occurrence
                    throw new Exception("client disconnected during post: to_read: " + toRead + "");
                }
                toRead -= numread;
                await ms.WriteAsync(buf, 0, numread);
            }
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        }
        //Got all the data we need so handle the request
        await Srv.HandlePostRequestAsync(this, new StreamReader(ms));
    }
```

So before I go into further details, the basic flow is as follows:

1. Start listening socket
2. Accept new connection
3. Process it if it is a HTTP POST
4. Get the HTTP Data
5. Do something with it
6. Reply with result

The error I am getting is in the `HttpProccessor` class. And it seems to happen when I read 0 bytes from the stream, but according to my content_length there should be more. What could cause this occurrence to happen?

1: Open TCP Listening Socket:

```
public void Listen()
{
    _isListening = true;
    _listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Port);
    _listener.Start();
    while (_isListening)
    {
        try
        {                    
            TcpClient s = _listener.AcceptTcpClient();                    
            Task.Run(() => ProcessRequest(s, this));                  
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {              
            Log.E(e);
            // Wait before trying again
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }
    Log.E("Stopping Listening Server");
}
```

2: Process the request:

```
private static async Task ProcessRequest(TcpClient socket, HttpServer server)
{
    var processor = new HttpProcessor(socket, server);
    try
    {
        await processor.ProcessAsync();
        //Close socket when done
        await processor.CloseSocketAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.E(ex);
        processor.CloseSocket();
    }
    finally
    {
        //Clear Up HTTP Processor resources
        processor.Dispose();
    }
}
```

3: The `HttpProcessor` class  (sorry its quite long)

```
/// <summary>
/// Class taken from git hub and modified to suit for my own use.
/// </summary>
public class HttpProcessor : IDisposable
{
    // Flag: Has Dispose already been called? 
    private bool _disposed = false;
    // Instantiate a SafeHandle instance.
    private readonly SafeHandle _handle = new SafeFileHandle(IntPtr.Zero, true);
    //

    public TcpClient Socket;
    public HttpServer Srv;

    private Stream _inputStream;
    public StreamWriter OutputStream;

    public string HttpMethod;
    public string HttpUrl;
    public string HttpProtocolVersionstring;
    public Dictionary<string, string> HttpHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    private const int MaxPostSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; // 1MB
    private const int BufSize = 4096;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="s">Socket</param>
    /// <param name="srv">Parent Reference</param>
    public HttpProcessor(TcpClient s, HttpServer srv)
    {
        Socket = s;
        Srv = srv;
        GetSocketStreams();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the handles to the input and output socket streams
    /// </summary>
    private void GetSocketStreams()
    {
        // we can't use a StreamReader for input, because it buffers up extra data on us inside it's
        // "processed" view of the world, and we want the data raw after the headers
        _inputStream = new BufferedStream(Socket.GetStream());

        // we probably shouldn't be using a stream writer for all output from handlers either
        OutputStream = new StreamWriter(new BufferedStream(Socket.GetStream()));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Closes the socket correctly
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task CloseSocketAsync()
    {
        // Done with request so close the socket and connection
        await OutputStream.FlushAsync();
        // bs.Flush(); // flush any remaining output
        _inputStream = null; OutputStream = null; // bs = null;            
        Socket.Close();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Closes the socket correctly
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public void CloseSocket()
    {
        // Done with request so close the socket and connection
        OutputStream.Flush();
        // bs.Flush(); // flush any remaining output
        _inputStream = null; OutputStream = null; // bs = null;            
        Socket.Close();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Process the http request
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task ProcessAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            await ParseRequestAsync();
            await ReadHeadersAsync();
            if (HttpMethod.Equals("POST"))
            {
                await HandlePostRequestAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                //We do not support any other types of requests
                await WriteFailureAsync(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.E(ex);
            WriteFailure();
        }
    }

    private static async Task<string> StreamReadLineAsync(Stream inputStream)
    {
        int next_char;
        string data = "";
        while (true)
        {
            next_char = inputStream.ReadByte();
            if (next_char == '\n') { break; }
            if (next_char == '\r') { continue; }
            if (next_char == -1) { await Task.Delay(1); continue; };
            data += Convert.ToChar(next_char);
        }
        return data;
    }

    public async Task ParseRequestAsync()
    {
        string request = await StreamReadLineAsync(_inputStream);
        string[] tokens = request.Split(' ');
        if (tokens.Length != 3)
        {
            throw new Exception("invalid http request line");
        }
        HttpMethod = tokens[0].ToUpper();
        HttpUrl = tokens[1];
        HttpProtocolVersionstring = tokens[2];
    }

    public async Task ReadHeadersAsync()
    {
        // Console.WriteLine("readHeaders()");
        String line;
        while ((line = await StreamReadLineAsync(_inputStream)) != null)
        {
            if (line.Equals(""))
            {
                // Got the headers so return
                return;
            }

            int separator = line.IndexOf(':');
            if (separator == -1)
            {
                throw new Exception("invalid http header line: " + line);
            }
            String name = line.Substring(0, separator);
            int pos = separator + 1;
            while ((pos < line.Length) && (line[pos] == ' '))
            {
                pos++; // strip any spaces
            }

            string value = line.Substring(pos, line.Length - pos);
            //     Console.WriteLine("header: {0}:{1}", name, value);
            HttpHeaders[name] = value;
        }
    }

    public async Task HandlePostRequestAsync()
    {
        // this post data processing just reads everything into a memory stream.
        // this is fine for smallish things, but for large stuff we should really
        // hand an input stream to the request processor. However, the input stream 
        // we hand him needs to let him see the "end of the stream" at this content 
        // length, because otherwise he won't know when he's seen it all! 

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        if (HttpHeaders.ContainsKey("Content-Length"))
        {
            var contentLen = Convert.ToInt32(HttpHeaders["Content-Length"]);
            if (contentLen > MaxPostSize)
            {
                throw new Exception($"POST Content-Length({contentLen}) too big for this simple server");
            }
            byte[] buf = new byte[BufSize];
            int toRead = contentLen;
            while (toRead > 0)
            {
                int numread = await _inputStream.ReadAsync(buf, 0, Math.Min(BufSize, toRead));
                if (numread == 0)
                {
                    if (toRead == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    //NOTE: Some times getting error here, seems to keep happening after first occurrence
                    throw new Exception("client disconnected during post: to_read: " + toRead + "");
                }
                toRead -= numread;
                await ms.WriteAsync(buf, 0, numread);
            }
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        }
        //Got all the data we need so handle the request
        await Srv.HandlePostRequestAsync(this, new StreamReader(ms));
    }

    public void WriteSuccess(string contentType = "application/json")
    {
        // this is the successful HTTP response line
        OutputStream.WriteLine("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
        // these are the HTTP headers...          
        OutputStream.WriteLine("Content-Type: " + contentType);
        OutputStream.WriteLine("Connection: close");
        // ..add your own headers here if you like
        OutputStream.WriteLine(""); // this terminates the HTTP headers.. everything after this is HTTP body..
    }

    public async Task WriteSuccessAsync(string contentType = "application/json")
    {
        // this is the successful HTTP response line
        await OutputStream.WriteLineAsync("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
        // these are the HTTP headers...          
        await OutputStream.WriteLineAsync("Content-Type: " + contentType);
        await OutputStream.WriteLineAsync("Connection: close");
        // ..add your own headers here if you like
        await OutputStream.WriteLineAsync(""); // this terminates the HTTP headers.. everything after this is HTTP body..
    }

    public void WriteFailure(HttpStatusCode errorCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
    {
        // this is an http 404 failure response
        //OutputStream.WriteLine("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
        OutputStream.WriteLine("HTTP/1.0 " + (int)errorCode);
        // these are the HTTP headers
        OutputStream.WriteLine("Connection: close");
        // ..add your own headers here
        OutputStream.WriteLine(""); // this terminates the HTTP headers.
    }

    public async Task WriteFailureAsync(HttpStatusCode errorCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
    {
        // this is an http failure response
        //await OutputStream.WriteLineAsync("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
        await OutputStream.WriteLineAsync("HTTP/1.0 " + (int)errorCode);
        // these are the HTTP headers
        await OutputStream.WriteLineAsync("Connection: close");
        // ..add your own headers here
        await OutputStream.WriteLineAsync(""); // this terminates the HTTP headers.
    }


    /// <summary>
    ///  Public implementation of Dispose pattern callable by consumers. 
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Protected implementation of Dispose pattern. 
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed) return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            _handle.Dispose();
            // Free any other managed objects here. 
            _inputStream.Dispose();
            OutputStream.Dispose();
            //
        }

        // Free any unmanaged objects here. 
        _disposed = true;
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (next_char == -1) { await Task.Delay(1); continue; };` is an unrelated bug, fyi. -1 means stream end.